# One side of python boxplot/violinplot not showing outlines

Tags: python, pandas, plot, boxplot, violin-plot

I cannot figure out why one side of my plot is not showing outlines. FWIW, other y-variables have produced complete plots with the same code.

First side of the chart is produced perfectly, so wondering if there is an axis limit error preventing the plots from completing?

The model for this code can be found on https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/web-ggbetweenstats-with-matplotlib

Data:

| category | y-data | y data that worked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 70 | 67 |
| 2 | 37 | 44 |
| 1 | 15 | 34 |
| 1 | 43 | 59 |
| 2 | 39 | 51 |
| 2 | 38 | 55 |
| 1 | 20 | 29 |
| 1 | 3 | 24 |

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st
df = pd.read_csv('Plots.csv')
psqi = df.dropna()
psqi['y'] = pd.to_numeric(psqi['y'], errors='coerce')
psqi["Category_Split"] = psqi["Category_Split"].replace({1: "Poor", 2: "Good"})
categories = ["Poor", "Good"]
y_data = [psqi[psqi["Category_Split"] == category]['y'].values for category in categories]

# Create jittered version of "x" (which is only 0, 1)
jitter = 0.032
x_data = [np.array([i] * len(d)) for i, d in enumerate(y_data)]
x_jittered = [x + st.t(df=6, scale=jitter).rvs(len(x)) for x in x_data]

# Add violins ----------------------------------------------------
# bw_method="silverman" means the bandwidth of the kernel density
# estimator is computed via Silverman's rule of thumb. 
# More on this in the bonus track ;)

# The output is stored in 'violins', used to customize their appearence
violins = ax.violinplot(
    y_data, 
    positions=POSITIONS,
    widths=0.45,
    bw_method="silverman",
    showmeans=False, 
    showmedians=False,
    showextrema=False
)

# Customize violins (remove fill, customize line, etc.)
for pc in violins["bodies"]:
    pc.set_facecolor("none")
    pc.set_edgecolor(BLACK)
    pc.set_linewidth(1.4)
    pc.set_alpha(1)
    

# Add boxplots ---------------------------------------------------
# Note that properties about the median and the box are passed
# as dictionaries.

medianprops = dict(
    linewidth=4, 
    color=GREY_DARK,
    solid_capstyle="butt"
)
boxprops = dict(
    linewidth=2, 
    color=GREY_DARK
)

ax.boxplot(
    y_data,
    positions=POSITIONS, 
    showfliers = False, # Do not show the outliers beyond the caps.
    showcaps = False,   # Do not show the caps
    medianprops = medianprops,
    whiskerprops = boxprops,
    boxprops = boxprops
)

# Add jittered dots ----------------------------------------------
for x, y, color in zip(x_jittered, y_data, COLOR_SCALE):
    ax.scatter(x, y, s = 100, color=color, alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

No errors generated. No search has helped so far.

Comment: When I tried with `tips` data, it worked perfectly. The only way I could achieve above figure is if `POSITIONS=[0]` and violinplot and boxplot used `y_data[0]`. Something to do with data, check x_data and y_data, might get a clue... pls post (as text) enough data to replicate the problem

Comment: @redox Thank you I have added data. Interesting about position, but the data shows perfectly, however boxplot/violin did not generate at the "1" position

Comment: It worked correctly for both the y columns. I don't think there is any problem with the code. Sorry, not able to replicate the issue. May be try on a different machine/env?

Comment: After further inspection I was able to find a solution. Thank you @Redox

Answer (score 0):

After further review "dropna(subset=['y-data'])", was added to remove the rows where 'y-data' is NaN or an empty string before plotting.

The dropna() function didn't resolve the issue because it only removes rows with NaN values, but not missing or invalid data, such as empty strings (''). The data must have contained an empty string.